# how compiler and interpreter work in case of array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-construction, interpreter

Recently I read somewhere that if an array dimensions are given at run time such a program can be interpreted but can not be compiled.

like in this following C++ code

```
int m;
cin >> m;
int a[m];
```

I’ve compiled it using turbo C++ and it's giving me error that a constant expression is needed for array declaration.(expected)

but in case of Java

```
int m;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
m = input.nextInt();
int[] a = new int[m];
```

It doesn't give any error. (I guess because it's interpreted not compiled)
but why this difference?

Comment: A. Java is a compiled language. B. This validation is per compiler implementation.

Comment: my question was not about java or c++, it's about how such a program can not be compiled but can be interpreted, where array dimensions are declared at run time.

Answer (score 2):

First, C++ and Java are both compiled language. And C++ also supports what you did in Java(dynamic allocation):

```
int m;
cin >> m;
int *a = new int[m];
```

The problem with your C++ code is that an array must have a constant size which is determined in compile time.

But your saying:

> an array dimensions are given at run time such a program can be interpreted but can not be compiled.

is wrong either, C, a compiled language, supports variable length arrays.

Comment: You should mention that you need to delete the array at some point.